# A question on the Pell equation $x^2-pqy^2 = -1$, with prime $p,q$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

We know that a necessary but not sufficient condition such that,

$$x^2-dy^2 = -1\tag1$$

is solvable is that $d$ is not divisible by a prime of form $4m+3$. It is not sufficient because the prime factors of $d$ may be *both* of form $4m+1$ yet is still unsolvable, like,

$$x^2-5\cdot41y^2 = -1\tag2$$

It made me wonder what were the relatives of $(2)$.

> **Question:** Let $p< q$ and be primes of form $4m+1$. Is it true that a ***necessary (but not sufficient)*** condition such that
>
> $$x^2-pqy^2 = -1\tag3$$
>
> is ***not*** solvable is that $q$ has form $q=u^2+pv^2$?

I checked with the [Alpertron](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM) for *all* small prime $q=4m+1$ and the list of unsolvable $q$ starts as,

$$p=5;\;q = 5, 41, 61, 101, 109, 149, 181, 241, 269, 281, 389, 401, 409, 421, 449,\dots$$

which are *all* of form $u^2+5v^2,$ and

$$p=13;\;q = 13, 17, 29, 53, 61, 113, 157, 181, 269, 313, 337, 373, 389,\dots$$

which are *all* of form $u^2+13v^2.$

However, $(3)$ *can* be solvable for some $q=u^2+pv^2$, hence the condition is not sufficient to guarantee non-solvability.

So is the answer true or false? If false, can one give a counter-example of a non-solvable prime pair $p,q$ of form $4m+1$ with $q\neq u^2+pv^2$?